# Problems using c:foreach with ui:include

Tags: java, jsf

I have an arraylist with a custom object type named "StartsideElement".

```
 <c:forEach items="#{startsideClient.brukerelementer}" var="element" begin="0" step="1">                         
  <div class="#{element.headerStyle}">
   <div>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr height="25px">
      <td width="5px">
       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_lefttop.gif" width="5" height="5" />
       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_left.gif" width="5" height="15" />

       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_leftbottom.gif" width="5" height="5" />
      </td>
      <td background="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_bg.gif" style="width: 920px;">
       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/Calendar_16x16.png" width="16" height="16" style="float:left; margin-bottom:2px;"/>
      <div class="headerText" style="text-align:left; position:relative; left: 15px; margin-top:2px"><h:outputText value="#{element.tittel}" /></div>
      </td>
      <td width="5px">
       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_righttop.gif" width="5" height="5" />

       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_right.gif" width="5" height="15" />
       <img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/gfx/topmenu_rightbottom.gif" width="5" height="5" />
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
   <!-- InnholdsDIV til Kommende oppgaver -->
   <div class="#{element.boxStyle}" style="clear: both;">          
    <div class="boxDokumenterFont">                            
     <ui:include src="#{element.mal}" />       
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END CONTAINER FOR WIDGET -->             
 </c:forEach>
```

The problem here is that the loop c:foreach will loop 6 times, which is correct, but the value of element will change as i use it. The title of the box created `<h:outputText value="#{element.tittel}" />` will not correnspond with the correct value. If I do: `<h:outputText value="#{element.tittel element.tittel}" />` the value printed by `element.tittel` will not be the same both places.

Any suggestions on what to do would be great. I cannot use `<ui:repeat>` because the `#{element.mal}` contains a filename that I need to pass to ui:include and that doesn't work with `ui:repeat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the title 
     `<h:outputText value="#{element.tittel}" />` within your custom object "StartsideElement" is changing as the jsf code iterates over your arrayList.  You would like that value to remain static and not change.

Why not create another attribute in your "StartsideElement" custom object that has the correct corresponding value?

Comment: I think he means the `element` changes not only at each loop iteration but also each time it is referenced, which sounds like a bug.  But maybe I'm reading the description incorrectly.

Comment: The problem was that the element changed as toto2 said every time i accessed the element. Solved my issue by building the code another way because of time constraints.